# Android Leanback : Headeritem in groups

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv, leanback

Hi i have been trying for a while to replicate the header as highlighted in the picture in blue rectangle..

i have several categories with sub categories in my application an would like to use the same type of thing as in the picture to keep things tidy and organised.

[image]

Any Help Would be very much apreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DividerRow:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/DividerRow

```
rowsAdapter = new CustomArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
...
...
...
rowsAdapter.add(new DividerRow());
```

Comment: that worked a treat although how would i add the grey text with the dividerRow??

Comment: You should have a look at SectionRow: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/SectionRow

rowsAdapter.add(new SectionRow(strHeader));